# References suggested for multivariate analysis of several similar time series

Tags: time-series, multivariate-regression, vector-autoregression

I have a time series dataset that reports the hourly page views and social media shares of online news stories. What I hope to obtain is the relationship between the two variables. I would imagine that the more shares a story gets, the more page views it will attract, and vice versa. That means the two variables would demonstrate a similar fast/slow growth curve.

In terms of a single story, I can use VAR (vector autoregressive) model to estimate the coefficients. However, how could I make use of hundreds of stories to build a more generalized model? What I've thought of so far is to fit each story with the same model and then observe the distribution of the coefficients. Would it be an appropriate method?

That would be great if you could kindly cite some papers and/or R packages that would inspire potential solutions. Thank you!